# Weird condition with static var that only appears on debug builds of gcc

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, gdb, mingw

I have a weird condition that only appears on gcc -O0 -g output, not on gcc -O3, not on MSVC, not on MSVC debug output.

```
void func(void) {
  static int enabled;

  if (!enabled) {
    // do stuff
    enabled = 1;
   }

}
```

The problem that appears on gcc -O0 -g only is that sometimes enabled returns to 0. But not always, only at some rare points in the execution of the program. The function loops through it generally. What could make it be confused about it? Could that 'enabled' be altered externally? But it's declared inside it.

EDIT: There is a way for it to be set to 0 inside the function but that is preceded with a big fat printf which is not printed at all [and there is no logical way for it to occur at all under the testing conditions]. It doesn't appear to be going at all to anything that explicitly does enabled = 0.

EDIT2: It is only called by the main thread.

EDIT3: It gets more bizarre. It doesn't appear on linux gcc -O0 -g but only on mingw-w64 [gcc -O0 -g].

EDIT4: An rwatch and watch on enabled appeared to show it being altered in some cases of if (!enabled) (which should be reading only).

EDIT5: After help from #mingw-w64 at oftc it appears it 'fixes' if the 'boolean sequence' is reversed, e.g. enabled is initialized to 1 and then set to 0. "by initializing static variable by non-zero value, puts it into the .data section" "so there is an issue about lcomm" "I assume that you have a buffer-overrun at some other place in your code"

Comment: Document whether or not this function can be called by multiple threads.

Comment: No, it is only called by the main thread.

Comment: Where is the initializer for that variable? Because right now it's not initialized to anything - I assume you'd like it to initially be 0? Also how did you determine that it goes back to being 0?

Comment: It's static. It's initialized to 0. It goes back to 0 because in the 'do stuff' a printf reports it, and I explicitly printf'ed its value.

Comment: Have you tried using gdb and setting up a write watchpoint on that variable?

Comment: As it is I cannot see anything that would affect that variable. It could be some logic error on your part, or some kind of stack corruption. You might want to try running your program under valgrind - it might be able to catch something.

Comment: It gets more bizarre. It doesn't appear on linux gcc -O0 -g but only on mingw-w64 [gcc -O0 -g].

Comment: Try valgrind under Linux anyway. Sometimes it catches subtle errors that only manifest once each millenium. I suppose it could be a compiler bug - but it's more probable that there's something wrong with your code. Without the code I cannot really say more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess: you have a buffer overflow somewhere. The variable that is in main memory right before `enabled` gets overwritten with the wrong size, overwriting everything after it also. Alternatively, you have a stray pointer that overwrites it.

The only useful way to debug this further is to add a watchpoint in gdb, as suggested by thkala.

Comment: I found it. It was a clear overflow on a variable in a function executed right before it (a short int that fixes the behavior if it goes to int). Now I only need to find out what exactly should be its size to make it bullet proof (not that it's absolutely necessary but why not, hehe).

Comment: Hah, what had fooled me (when I had set it to short int) was that that particular variable was in the end very small. However, along the way it was part of a more complex floating calculation.

Comment: Ah, correction, it happened when the short ints were parameters in a function that writes them. It should be easier since the error is probably not respecting the input size required by them.

Comment: Yep, that it was, a Microsoft function that required UINT.